# Scale selection for the Hyperparameters

Tags: neural-networks, hyperparameter

During the scale selection for hyperparameters

I have a question generally if we have to select a random number in the interval $[2,5]$

It is fairly straight forward that we select either $2,3,4,5$ just by using the linear scale

But my friend pointed out if I have to select a random number in the interval $[0.0001,1]$ he said using the linear scale has a problem that

$90\%$ of the time I will be selecting between $[0.1,1]$ interval and $10\%$ I will be selecting from the interval $[0.0001,0.1]$

I was unable to understand how this is the case?

He suggested me to use logarithmic scale for selecting the number if it is in the interval $[0.0001,1]$, Because both 0.0001 and 1 are at different orders of magnitude

If I understand the order of magnitude properly in the interval $[2,5]$ the order of magnitude is $10^0$

But not in the case of interval $[0.0001,1]$ because one is $1*10^{-4}$ and the other is $1*10^0$

Can you please explain how will the logarithmic scale will be helpful? when the orders of magnitude are different why they cant be accomplished using the linear scale?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use linear scale (say 5 values) for the range $[0.0001, 1]$, the hyperparameter set you'll be trying will look like *approximately* as follows: $$\mathcal H=[0.0001, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 1]$$

In this selection, the values you try is within the range $[0.1,1]$ $80\%$ of the time (i.e. 4 out of 5). If you increase the number of in-between steps/values linearly, this probability will get closer to $90\%$. If you were using the logarithmic scale, then the values would look like as follows:
$$\mathcal H=[0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]$$

Which one to use depends on the application and the set of the hyper-parameters you want to explore.  For example, if you're trying various learning rates in neural nets, logarithmic steps are the typical choice and more useful.

As a rule of thumb, you use logarithmic scales to observe the effect of multiplicative changes in your HP, and you use linear scales to observe additive effects in your HP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, If you take more than five values then the probability changes right? for the linear scale or is there something I am missing? Kindly reply

Comment: Yes, it changes and converges to 90% approx.

Comment: No I meant the values between 0.0001 and 0.1 will increase no?

Comment: That results in less probability right?

Comment: If you take linearly scaled uniform samples between $0.0001$ and $1$, you'll also have values between $0.0001$ and $0.1$ in addition to values between $0.1$ and $1$. Forget about $0.0001$ (since it's close to zero and explaining with it is not the simplest thing to do) and think about the interval (line segment) $[0,1]$ on the real axis. And, think about marking the line segment at regular intervals, and assume you have lots of marks. The segment $[0,0.1]$ will approximately cover 1/10 of the marks (since it's 1/10 of the whole line segment) and the remaining part will cover 9/10 of the marks.

Comment: Understood so any interval we take for example $[0.0001,100]$ here I can take the interval $[1,100]$ covers the most of the part that is mostly $99.999999\%$ and the other interval i.e. $[0.0001,1]$ is around $0.000001\%$? is my understanding right? If so generally when you consider taking a random number in this interval $[0.00001,1]$ is always much biased towards the interval $[0.1,1]$?  is that true? the probability of selecting the random number in the interval $[0.0001,0.1]$ is very less?

Comment: Yes, if your random selection is uniform.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation of the concept, Can you please point me a link or something how uniform random selection is done?

Comment: Recall that in your original question, it's just selection of numbers uniformly in an interval. It's not random selection. But, uniformly and randomly selecting numbers from an interval  can be achieved by rand() function in Matlab, np.random.random() function in Python etc.